# Allowing GPS while debugging ionic on device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-debug

I'm making ionic app that uses GPS and compass. I want to test on real device using `ionic cordova run android --device --livereload` cmd.
Problem is that it connects to my IP and that's why GPS is not available. Is there a way to add my IP to whitelist? How?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer on this